# Issue with Retrieving JSON from Webpage Android

Tags: java, android, json, eclipse

So I'm facing some difficulty in trying to, what seems simply, obtain a JSON file from a webpage, and then parse it on Android. I have already built the parser, and tested it in Eclipse (in fact, all of the code works in Eclipse). However, when I run the HttpURLConnection and try to retrieve the JSON data in a string in Android Studio, I end up getting no exceptions and an almost empty string (I think I am getting the 1st, 2nd, 3rd, and last character, but not too sure). I have included parts of the code below, and

```
URL url = null;
    HttpURLConnection urc = null;
    try {
        url = new URL(query);
        urc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urc.getInputStream());
        jsoncontent = readStream(in);
        System.out.println(jsoncontent);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        urc.disconnect();
    }
```

The code for readStream() is below

```
private static String readStream(InputStream is) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is),1000);
    for (String line = r.readLine(); line != null; line =r.readLine()){
        sb.append(line);
    }
    is.close();
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the output of the print statement? Also, try removing the size limit from the `BufferedReader` constructor in your `readStream()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an exact chunk from an assignment I did last semester:

```
URL u = new URL(url);
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/html");
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
JSONObject searchResults = new JSONObject(in.readLine());
...

conn.disconnect();
```

You seem to be missing setRequestMethod("GET") and setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/html") in your code.  Hope this helps.